# Java Arrays.sort() nor suitable method found for sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, lambda, comparator

I have an int[] array. I am trying to sort it using its median value. I sorted it first, calculated its median value and then sorting again using lambda expression as comparator.

But the compiler gives an error:

```
no suitable method found for sort(int[],(int a, in[...]n); })
        Arrays.sort(arrCopy, (int a, int b) -> {
```

My code

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
int median = arr[(arr.length - 1) / 2];
Arrays.sort(arrCopy, (int a, int b) -> {
            return (Math.abs(a - median) == Math.abs(b - median)) ? Math.abs(a - b) : Math.abs(a - median) - Math.abs(b - median);
        });
```

I want to sort numbers based on its absolute difference with median.

Comment: If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#i171), so will see that the only overload that takes a `Comparator` is for a generic array, and generics can't be primitives, so there is no method for sorting numbers by anything other than natural order. You need to box the primitive values before you can apply alternate sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `IntStream` and build the stream from the array of int values

```
        int[] result = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().sorted((a, b) -> {
            return (Math.abs(a - median) == Math.abs(b - median)) ? Math.abs(a - b)
                    : Math.abs(a - median) - Math.abs(b - median);
        }).mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()).toArray();
```